# Is it possible to use a .ui file from Qt Designer in Qt Designer as a custom widget?

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I always thought that one could just make a new Widget in Qt-Designer, save it as a .ui file; and then import that .ui file back in Qt Designer as a custom widget. But, now I've decided to try it, and I'm looking on the net, and cannot find any references to this.

So, can someone confirm, if it is possible to use just a .ui file as a template for a custom widget file in Qt Designer - without any C++ or Python code? If so, how do you do that?

Comment: No, it is not possible since the .ui is only a set of instructions to implement a Qt Widget but it is not a Qt Widget.

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc - feel free to post that as an answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @eyllanesc is correct, taking your question literally. You said: "without any C++ or Python code", and there lays the problem. But if you can give up that restriction, there is yet some hope.

The ".ui" files are XML. Usually, in a C++ project, the Qt's "uic" tool translates each ".ui" file into a header that is included in a source .cpp file and compiled as usual. There is another way, though. Qt has an `uitools` module, providing a `QUiLoader` class for [loading widgets at runtime](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#run-time-form-processing) from .ui files dynamically (including runtime-connected signals and slots between their components). There are a number of examples illustrating this technique: [Text Finder](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtuitools-textfinder-example.html), [Calculator Builder](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-calculatorbuilder-example.html) and [World Time Clock Builder](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-worldtimeclockbuilder-example.html). You also can [create plugins](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/adding-plugins.html) for the designer, adding your own widgets to the designer palette like the [World Time Clock Plugin](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-worldtimeclockplugin-example.html) example.

So the proposal is: create a designer plugin widget that loads .ui files at runtime (from disk files or embedded resources). This requires some code and work, but it would be compiled and installed only once, and you would be able to instantiate it any number of times in different projects with different .ui forms.